# Casting in C: gotchas

Tags: c, casting

I am programming an Atmel SAMD20 in C. I came upon an error, that I have now fixed, but I'm not quite sure why it happened in the first place. Can someone point it out to me? (it's probably far too obvious, and I'm going to facepalm later.)

An array of sensors is generating `uint16_t` data, which I converted to `uint8_t` to send over I2C. So, this is how I originally wrote it:

```
for (i = 0; i < SENSBUS1_COUNT; ++i)
{
  write_buffer[ (i*2) ] = (uint8_t) sample_sensbus1[i] & 0xff;
  write_buffer[(i*2)+1] = (uint8_t) sample_sensbus1[i] >> 8;
}
```

Here, `write_buffer` is `uint8_t` and `sample_sensbus1` is `uint16_t`.

This, for some reason, ends up messing up the most significant byte (in most cases, the most significant byte is just 1 (i.e. 0x100)). This, on the other hand, works fine, and is exactly what it should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < SENSBUS1_COUNT; ++i)
{
  write_buffer[ (i*2) ] = sample_sensbus1[i] & 0xff;
  write_buffer[(i*2)+1] = sample_sensbus1[i] >> 8;
}
```

Clearly, the implicit cast is smarter than I am.

What is going on?

Comment: Moral of the story: **PARENTHESES!** *facepalm*

Comment: And coffee.....

Comment: can't `uint8_t` legally alias other types, anyways?  I feel the bit-masking and bit-shifting can be avoided if all you want is to access a `uint16_t` array as a `uint8_t` array.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I'm not exactly sure if this is what you mean, but you can access a `uint16_t` as `uint8_t` with an implicit cast. It will chop off the higher byte. But you cannot automatically have it generate a `uint8_t` array of this kind.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Which part is chopped off also is probably system-dependent. It is hard to tell. Perhaps on *big-endian* systems, the lower byte is chopped off. Don't quote me on that, but it's probably true.

Comment: So assuming you created a `uint8_t *` that pointed to the `uint16_t` array, there would not be a problem with them being cut off, as you could index the whole set of data with byte indexes (there would be twice as many elements in the `uint8_t` array).  But as you mentioned endianness, that did remind me that the order of the bytes would, in fact, be system dependent.

Comment: @ShreyasVinod Nope, C is smarter than that. If you cast a `uint16_t` to `uint8_t` on a big-endian system, you'll still chop off the more-significant byte. However, it is true that if you cast a *pointer*—i.e. `uint16_t *` to `uint8_t *` on big-endian, you will indeed lose the less-significant byte when you dereference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
write_buffer[(i*2)+1] = (uint8_t) sample_sensbus1[i] >> 8;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
write_buffer[(i*2)+1] = ((uint8_t) sample_sensbus1[i]) >> 8;
```

As you see, it does the cast before it does the shift. Your most significant byte is now gone.

This should work, though:

```
write_buffer[(i*2)+1] = (uint8_t) (sample_sensbus1[i] >> 8);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your cast converts the `uint16_t` to `uint8_t` before it does the shift or mask.  It is treated as though you wrote:

```
write_buffer[ (i*2) ] = ((uint8_t)sample_sensbus1[i]) & 0xff;
write_buffer[(i*2)+1] = ((uint8_t)sample_sensbus1[i]) >> 8;
```

You might need:

```
write_buffer[ (i*2) ] = (uint8_t)(sample_sensbus1[i] & 0xff);
write_buffer[(i*2)+1] = (uint8_t)(sample_sensbus1[i] >> 8);
```

In practice, the uncast version is OK too.  Remember, a cast tells the compiler "I know more about this than you do; do as I say".  That's dangerous if you don't know more than the compiler.  Avoid casts whenever you can.

You might also note that shifting (left or right) by the size of the type in bits (or more) is undefined behaviour.  However, the `((uint8_t)sample_sensbus[i]) >> 8` is not undefined behaviour, because of the 'usual arithmetic conversions' which mean that the result of `(uint8_t)sample_sensbus[i]` is converted to `int` before the shift occurs, and the size of an `int` cannot be 8 bits (it must be at least 16 bits to satisfy the standard), so the shift is not too big.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question of operator precedence. In the first example, you are first converting to `uint8_t` and are applying the `&` and `>>` operators second. In the second example, those are applied before the implicit conversion takes place.

Comment: Darn the missing parentheses. I knew it. *facepalm*

Answer (score 3):

Casting is a unary prefix operator and as such has very high precedence.

```
(uint8_t) sample_sensbus1[i] & 0xff
```

parses as

```
((uint8_t)sample_sensbus1[i]) & 0xff
```

In this case `& 0xff` is redundant. But:

```
(uint8_t) sample_sensbus1[i] >> 8
```

parses as

```
((uint8_t)sample_sensbus1[i]) >> 8
```

Here the cast truncates the number to 8 bits, then `>> 8` shifts everything out.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this expression:

```
(uint8_t) sample_sensbus1[i] >> 8;
```

It is doing the following sequence:

1. Converting the `sample_sensbus1[i]` to `uint8_t`, effectively *truncating* it to the 8 least significant bits. This is where you are losing your data.
2. Converting the above to `int` as a part of [usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8), making an int with only 8 lower bits set.
3. Shifting the above `int` right `8` bits, effectively making the whole expression zero.